# how to print function output

Tags: scheme, racket

I am new to `racket`. Please help me.

In my code, I defined `show1`. When I call `show1` from within another function, the bit image is not being drawn. But, when I call the function separately, as `(show1 a)`, it works.
is there any solution to print out of show1 function

```
(require racket/draw)
(require racket/gui)
(define target (make-bitmap 60 60)) ; A 30x30 bitmap
(define dc (new bitmap-dc% [bitmap target]))
(define board
  (lambda(ls call x y)
  ;(send dc draw-rectangle
    ;     0 0   ; Top-left at (0, 10), 10 pixels down from top-left
    ;    60 60)
  (if (even? call)
      (send dc set-brush "lightblue" 'solid)
      (send dc set-brush "white" 'solid))

  (send dc set-pen "black" 0 'transparent)
  (send dc draw-rectangle x y 20 20)
  (cond
    [(equal? (list-ref ls call) 'x)(printx x y) ]
    [(equal? (list-ref ls call) 'o)(printy x y) ]
    [(number? (list-ref ls call)) ])
  (cond
    [(< call 2) (board  ls (+ call 1) (+ x 20) 0)]
    [(= call 2) (board ls (+ call 1) 0 20)]
    [(and (> call 2) (< call 5)) (board ls (+ call 1) (+ x 20) 20)]
    [(= call 5) (board ls (+ call 1) 0 40)]
    [(and (> call 5) (< call 8))  (board ls (+ call 1) (+ x 20) 40)])
  target))

(define printx
  (lambda (x y)
    (send dc set-pen "red" 2 'solid) 
    (send dc draw-line x y (+ x 18) (+ y 18))
    (send dc draw-line (+ x 18) y x (+ y 18))))
(define printy
  (lambda (x y)
    (send dc set-pen "red" 2 'solid)
    (send dc set-brush "green" 'transparent)
    (send dc draw-rounded-rectangle x y 20 20 10)))

(require unstable/list)
(require racket/mpair)

(define sot 3)
(define a (build-list (* sot sot) values))
(define dummy 1)
(define play1
  (lambda (dummy)
            (set! dummy (+ 1 dummy))
            (play (- dummy 1))
            (play1 dummy)
            ))
(define show1
  (lambda (ls)
      (board a 0 0 0)))

" 0 1 2"
" 3 4 5"
" 6 7 8"
(newline)
(printf "Above shown is the address of the tic-tac-toe box \n")
;(newline)
(define firs 
  (lambda (value addr pla)

                (cond
                  [(> addr (- (* sot sot) 1)) (error "input error run it    again")]
                  [(number? (list-ref a addr)) (set! a (list-set a addr    pla))  (show1 a) (win a)]
                  [else (printf "error the box is already filled run it again\n") (firs value (read) pla)] )show1))
                  ;(set! dummy (- dummy 1))  
;[(error "error the box is already filled run it again")]

(define play
  (lambda (dummy)    
                (cond
                  [(> dummy (* sot sot)) (printf "MATCH DRAW \n")(exit)]
                  [(even? dummy) (print "second player") (newline) (set! dummy (+ 1 dummy))(firs dummy (read) 'o)]
                  [(not (even? dummy)) (print "first player")(newline) (firs dummy (read) 'x)])))

(define win
  (lambda (a)
    (cond [(and (equal? (list-ref a 0) (list-ref a 3)) (equal? (list-ref a 0) (list-ref a 6))) (cond [(equal? (list-ref a 0) 'x) (print "player 1 wins")(newline) (exit)]
                                                                                     [(equal? (list-ref a 0) 'o) (print "player 2 wins")(newline) (exit)])]
          [(and (equal? (list-ref a 1) (list-ref a 4)) (equal? (list-ref a 1) (list-ref a 7))) (cond [(equal? (list-ref a 1) 'x) (print "player 1 wins")(newline) (exit)]
                                                                                                     [(equal? (list-ref a 1) 'o) (print "player 2 wins")(newline) (exit)])]
          [(and (equal? (list-ref a 2) (list-ref a 5)) (equal? (list-ref a 2) (list-ref a 8))) (cond [(equal? (list-ref a 2) 'x) (print "player 1 wins")(newline) (exit)]
                                                                                                     [(equal? (list-ref a 2) 'o) (print "player 2 wins")(newline) (exit)])]
          [(and (equal? (list-ref a 0) (list-ref a 1)) (equal? (list-ref a 0) (list-ref a 2))) (cond [(equal? (list-ref a 0) 'x) (print "player 1 wins")(newline) (exit)]
                                                                                                     [(equal? (list-ref a 0) 'o) (print "player 2 wins")(newline) (exit)])]
          [(and (equal? (list-ref a 3) (list-ref a 4)) (equal? (list-ref a 3) (list-ref a 5))) (cond [(equal? (list-ref a 3) 'x) (print "player 1 wins")(newline) (exit)]
                                                                                                     [(equal? (list-ref a 3) 'o) (print "player 2 wins")(newline) (exit)])]
          [(and (equal? (list-ref a 6) (list-ref a 7)) (equal? (list-ref a 6) (list-ref a 8))) (cond [(equal? (list-ref a 6) 'x) (print "player 1 wins")(newline) (exit)]
                                                                                                     [(equal? (list-ref a 6) 'o) (print "player 2 wins")(newline) (exit)])]
          [(and (equal? (list-ref a 0) (list-ref a 4)) (equal? (list-ref a 0) (list-ref a 8))) (cond [(equal? (list-ref a 0) 'x) (print "player 1 wins")(newline) (exit)]
                                                                                                     [(equal? (list-ref a 0) 'o) (print "player 2 wins")(newline) (exit)])]
          [(and (equal? (list-ref a 2) (list-ref a 4)) (equal? (list-ref a 2)(list-ref a 6)))  (cond [(equal? (list-ref a 2) 'x) (print "player 1 wins")(newline) (exit)]
                                                                                                     [(equal? (list-ref a 2) 'o) (print "player 2 wins")(newline) (exit)])]
          [else (board a 0 0 0)]
          )));[(equal? value 8) (newline)"match draw"])))
(show1 a)
(play1 dummy)
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow! A lot of code. I have a meta-suggestion, and a suggestion.

1) Meta-suggestion: programming is all about learning how to figure out problems by yourself.  In this case, you want to see if you can strip out the parts of this giant program that *don't* affect the answer, to find a small program that shows the problem.

2) In this case, I think your problem is simply that values are printed when they're the result of top-level expressions, and not otherwise. To take a simple example, compare

```
#lang racket

(+ 3 4)
```

with

```
#lang racket

(+ (+ 1 2) 4)
```

Why doesn't the second one print "3", which is the result of `(+ 1 2)` ? It appears to me that this is the same reason that the result of `show1` is not being displayed.

Caveat: per point #1, it's hard to read the code because there's so much of it...